# how to fetch ecommerce data from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to fetch ecommerce data from google analytic for custom reporting using a php application. I need to fetch data like last 5 sales, total sales by date, by month etc. But, I am not getting any clue how to get data from analytic. Please give me a clue... Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to coding and is related to reporting. Try this for starters: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014872?hl=en

Comment: Hi, It's related to coding, as I told you I need to fetch summarized data from different websites, then I need to prepare a report and it will be displayed within a custom webpage.

Comment: Your must show that you've put in effort to resolve your question. If it is related to coding then show your own code attempts. What have you tried? What were the error messages you received?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am following this quickstart guide, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

and getting this error, http://puu.sh/ucYew/bff9ec92ba.png, the hosted link is http://www.technowebs.in/mockup/analytics/HelloAnalytics.html

Comment: Visit the URL listed in the error and add 'www.tchnoweb...' as an accepted JavaScript Origin.